# Hinge constraint: How to make body with mass = 1 be static and how to make body rotate an angle (e.g. 30 degrees)

Tags: cannon.js

In hinge official example: https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/hinge.html

1. Please help me to make the body with mass = 1 become static (currently it is oscillating).
2. How can I rotate the body an angle, for e.g. 30 degrees.

Comment: In your first question, what do you mean when you say “ static”? You could make it static by setting mass to zero, but it doesn’t make sense to connect two static bodies with a hinge.

Comment: Hi @schteppe, thanks for your comment.

I want to implement a simulation of servo motor. You can see in the picture: https://imgur.com/a/0C6ordC. Both static and rotation object have mass. There are two problem I have to solve:
1. Rotation part need to be fixed at an angle. When I use hinge, due to gravity, it will fall down (illustration: https://imgur.com/a/JrJd1Vk).
2. Rotation part need to rotate exactly angle from it previous position. In my image, it is 45 degrees.

Can you tell me a solution for this?

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. There are several ways of solving this.. What should happen if a strong force tries to work against the servos' motor force? Should it act like a spring, giving in at first, but then "spring back" into the desired rotation? Or should the motor use a rotational speed to get to the desired rotation?

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. By the way, can you tell me the unit of "v" in the function: frontLeftHinge.setMotorSpeed(v) of the demo?

Comment: Ok, cool. The intention is to use SI units throughout Cannon.js, so I guess rad/s.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and discuss with you later when i have result.